# How to insert a string in a sorted linked list in java?

Tags: java

I'm trying to make a sorted linkedlist. The addElement and removeElement methods works almost as they should except that the addElement method don't always insert the elements in the correct order.

Here's my code so far:

```
public class SortedLinkedList {

// Node class
class Node {
    public String data;
    public Node next;
}

// attributes
private Node first;
private int size;

public SortedLinkedList() {
    first = null;
}

public void addElement(String element) {
    if (first == null) {
        Node newNode = new Node();
        newNode.data = element;
        newNode.next = null;
        first = newNode;

        size++;

    } else if (first.toString().compareTo(element) > 0) {
        Node newNode = new Node();
        newNode.data = element;
        newNode.next = first;
        first = newNode;

        size++;

    } else {
        Node before = first;
        Node after = first.next;

        while (first.next != null) {
            Node newNode = new Node();
            newNode.data = element;

            if (after.toString().compareTo(element) > 0) {

                before.next = newNode;
                newNode.next = after;
            }

            before = after;
            after = after.next;
        }

        size++;
    }
}

public boolean removeElement(String element) {
    boolean removed = false;

    try {
        if (first.data.toString().equals(element)) {
            first = first.next;
            removed = true;

        } else {
            Node before = first;
            Node after = first.next;

            while (first.next != null) {
                if (after.data.toString().compareTo(element) == 0) {

                    before.next = after.next;
                    break;
                }

                before = after;
                after = after.next;
            }

            size--;
            removed = true;
        }
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        removed = false;
    }
    return removed;
}

public int countElements() {
    return size;
}

@Override
public String toString() {

String result = "{";
Node current = this.first;

while (current != null) {
    if (current.next != null) {
        result = result + current.data.toString() + ", ";
    } else {
        result = result + current.data.toString();
    }
    current = current.next;
}

result = result + "}";

return result;
}
```

For example, I have tried to insert the values: 'b, a, d, c' and the output is: 'c, d, a, b' but it should be 'a, b, c, d'.
I really can't see what I'm doing wrong.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You need to implement a `toString()`method in the class `Node` or directly access it with `.data` i.e. `first.data.compareTo(element)`.

Comment: sorry i have forgotten to insert the toString() method

Comment: why should it be in the Node class?

Comment: You shouldn't be using `toString` at all for comparison here. That's a method that is supposed to be used for to make the object human readable - and in your case, includes extra characters. instead you should use `first.data`.

Answer (score 1):

You have various small issues.

1. You are comparing the `Node` instead of the `Node`'s data.
2. Your while loop is looping `while (first.next != null)`. Shouldn't this be checking `before` or `after`?
3. Why are you creating the new `Node` inside the `while` loop?

You could change the `Node` like this:

```
class Node implements Comparable<Node> {
    private final String data; //once initialised shouldn't change
    private Node next; //this can change

    public Node(String data) {
       this.data = data;
    }

    public Node getNext() {
      return next;
    }

    public void setNext(Node next) {
      this.next = next;
    }

    public int  compareTo(Node that) {
      return this.data.compareTo(that.data);
    }
}
```

In your `addElement(String element)` I would immediately do the following before the `if` conditions, it is all the same:

```
Node newNode = new Node(element);
size++;
```

Your while loop in the last case can then be:

```
 Node after = first;

 while ((after != null) && (after.compareTo(newNode) <= 0)) {
     //we traverse to the next 
     before = after;
     after = after.getNext();
 }

 //either we found the spot, or it is the last element in the list
 before.setNext(newNode);
 newNode.setNext(after);
```

You can probably also include the case of when the new node should be inserted at the head of the list too... but I leave it to you.

Comment: I have tried to change them but it has not solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

If you want a sorted linked list, you can use the normal `LinkedList` library and call `List#sort(Comparator)` on it.

For example, if we want to sort Strings by alphabetical order:

```
LinkedList<String> list = new LinkedList<>();
list.addAll(Arrays.asList("b","d","c","a"));
System.out.println(list);  // ["b","d","c","a"]
list.sort(new Comparator<String>() {
    //This sorts the values by unicode value. In most cases, this results in sorting by alphabetical order
    @Override
    public int compare(String s1, String s2){
        return s1.compareToIgnoreCase(s2);
    }
});
System.out.println(list);  // ["a","b","c","d"]
```

Comment: One would assume that the OP is trying to implement it himself to learn about linked lists. If you wanted a sorted list using the JDK collections you would not use a `LinkedList` but something like a `PriorityQueue`, which is much more efficient.